# Form upload with PhP and AJAX to stop reloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a PHP form which reloads after submission. I used Ajax to stop reloading it and now it is not submitting the data in the database. Am I missing something here? Like I said if I remove the AJAX it works fine but page reloads. I know I am making a very tiny error.

Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <label for="name" class="control-lable" style="font-size:15px;">Name* :</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="query_name" id="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <label for="email" class="control-lable" style="font-size:15px;">Email* :</label>
       <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="query_email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label for="comments" class="control-lable" style="font-size:15px;">Message*:</label>
      <textarea id="comments"  class="form-control" name="query_message" rows="5" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" name="contactus" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </div> 
</form>
```

AJAX

```
 jQuery(function($) {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var str = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       cache: false,
       data:str,
       url:window.location.origin+'/post-page/',
       success:function() {
         console.log('email sent');
         $("#result").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close">×</button>Thank you for posting query, You will be replied in next 24 hours</div>');
         $("form").trigger("reset");
       }
      });
    });
  });
```

PHP

```
  if(isset($_POST['contactus'])){

    $query_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
    $query_name = strip_tags($_POST['query_name']);
    $query_email = strip_tags($_POST['query_email']);
    $query_message= strip_tags($_POST['query_message'], '<p><br>');

    $ins_query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO query (query_date, query_name, query_email, query_message) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

    $ins_query->bind_param("ssss", $query_date, $query_name, $query_email, $query_message);

    $ins_query->execute();
    $ins_query->close();

   }
```

Comment: In your ajax you do not send any data.

Comment: my mistake. please check now. Unfortunately, I am not very good at AJAX and have used code from other alike questions

Comment: Is your URL correct?  I mean the URL for Ajax posting

Comment: Why it shouldn't. If I remove AJAX, it works fine. I have this code, and it just stopping page to reload and not submitting any data.

Comment: yeah, it is a wordpress page. If I use page name then it's adding it at last of the url and making it 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying the filename extension in ajax `url` . Change to `your-php-form-handling-page.php`

In you `form` page, add id to form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="FrmSubmit" method="post" role="form">
<input type="hidden" name="path_uri" value="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?> id="path_uri">
```

In your `ajax` page

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#FrmSubmit").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var uri = $('#path_uri').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: uri+'/single-palliative.php',
            cache: false,
            data: $('#FrmSubmit').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                console.log('email sent');
                $("#result").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close">×</button>Thank you for posting query, You will be replied in next 24 hours</div>');
                $("#FrmSubmit").trigger("reset");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In your `filename.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['query_name']) && isset($_POST['query_date']) && isset($_POST['query_email']) && isset($_POST['query_message'])){

    $query_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
    $query_name = strip_tags($_POST['query_name']);
    $query_email = strip_tags($_POST['query_email']);
    $query_message= strip_tags($_POST['query_message'], '<p><br>');

    $ins_query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO query (query_date, query_name, query_email, query_message) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

    $ins_query->bind_param("ssss", $query_date, $query_name, $query_email, $query_message);

    $ins_query->execute();
    $ins_query->close();

}
```

**UPDATE**: Added hidden field in form and change uri in AJAX url.

Comment: It is a wordpress page and file-name.php is being used as custom template under that /post-page/ url. I meant to say, the /post-page/ is a url which loads the file-name.php. Do I still need to mention the file name?

Comment: You need to specify the exact filename with ext, where you are processing your php form.

Comment: http://localhost/palliative-care/single-palliative.php 404 (Not Found).. :( It doesn't take it that way

Comment: Inside your `form` page, add this anywhere inside the form:

<input type="hidden" name="path_uri" value="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?> id="path_uri">

and change your ajax form to the updated one above. I've updated the whole code in my post. Do check.

Comment: Just a quick question. It takes the date from the system and not send with the entered data. Should I still use isset($_POST['query_date'])? Do you think that would work.

Comment: Thanks Sreejith but console.log($(this).serialize()); coming blank.

Comment: Try
 console.log($('#FrmSubmit').serialize());

Comment: giving me 
path_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fmak&query_name=ajax&query_email=maklodian%40gmail.com&query_message=testing+again&captcha=39207

Comment: That is correct. Now in your single-palliative.php, add var_dump($_POST); just above isset statement and check if you are getting data in Network, two tabs ahead of console tab

Comment: how to check that data in the network? Before form submission, I can't locate the single-palliative.php page. When I do it, I have page appeared on the list. I print the var_dump and it gives `array (size=0) empty` before or after submission.

Comment: You are the Man! Finally able to do it, with your help, of course! but have a minor issue now. It's skipping the captcha process.

Answer (score 0):

1.) give the form an ID:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="formsid" method="post" role="form">
```

2.) edit your Ajax-function with the correct path to your php file, set data with the id of your form.

```
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       cache: false,
       data: $("#formsid").serialize(),
       url:path/to/phpfile.php,
       success:function() {
         console.log('email sent');
         $("#result").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close">×</button>Thank you for posting query, You will be replied in next 24 hours</div>');
         $("#formsid").trigger("reset");
       }
      });
```

3.) in PHP change if-statment:

```
if(is_array($_POST) && isset($_POST)) {
    //your code
} else {
    throw new Exception('Post is empty'.var_dump($_POST));
}
```

this should work!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactus">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <label for="name" class="control-lable" style="font-size:15px;">Name* :</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="query_name" id="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <label for="email" class="control-lable" style="font-size:15px;">Email* :</label>
       <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="query_email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label for="comments" class="control-lable" style="font-size:15px;">Message*:</label>
      <textarea id="comments"  class="form-control" name="query_message" rows="5" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" name="contactus" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </div> 
</form>
```

and then,

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="contactus"){

    $query_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
    $query_name = strip_tags($_POST['query_name']);
    $query_email = strip_tags($_POST['query_email']);
    $query_message= strip_tags($_POST['query_message'], '<p><br>');

    $ins_query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO query (query_date, query_name, query_email, query_message) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

    $ins_query->bind_param("ssss", $query_date, $query_name, $query_email, $query_message);

    $ins_query->execute();
    $ins_query->close();

   }
```

Comment: no changes to ur ajax code,just try.the whole logic behindnthis is that input type=submit is not the part of form data which u r using on ur php script side as $_POST['contactus'] so condition is nevr reach and ur php script will not run,that's i suggest u,try it may help u

Answer (score -1):

```
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           cache: false,
           data:{query_name:'query_name',query_email:'query_email',query_email:'query_email'},
           url:window.location.origin+'/post-page/',
           success:function() {
             console.log('email sent');
             $("#result").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close">×</button>Thank you for posting query, You will be replied in next 24 hours</div>');
             $("form").trigger("reset");
           }
          });
        });
      });
```

You should add `data: {<your data>}` in ajax

Comment: This is totally wrong.  OP has already serialized the form.  Also the question has been updated

Comment: And what about PhP code? I am using all this code on the same page

Comment: Yes, Akintunde! Like I said, I am not good in Ajax but using the code available on different alike questions.

Comment: Yes, Varman! No error in the console log. Otherwise, It must give an error. I have all the code on the same page and like I said, it runs the function, shows me "email sent" message in console and shows an alert. I think there is some problem with data thing. Have I done it correctly?